# iOS how to remove thin border line then use layer.cornerRadius

Tags: ios, core-graphics, layer, rounded-corners

I always use simple method to get view rounded corners

```
+ (void)setRoundedCornersByView:(UIView*) givenView roundAngle:(int)roundAngle borderWidth:(double)borderWidth borderColor:(UIColor*)borderColor alphaBorder:(double)alphaBorder {
    givenView.layer.cornerRadius = roundAngle;
    givenView.layer.borderColor = [[borderColor colorWithAlphaComponent:alphaBorder] CGColor];
    givenView.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    givenView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}
```

But now i got thin border around rounded line, it's a thin line which have color like background color of rounded view

[image]

How to remove it without use onDraw, because it's not possible to do - because it's mean i must override all iOS controls where i need rounded corners.

Also u try use

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:bound byRoundingCorners:corners cornerRadii:cornerRadii];
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = givenView.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
givenView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

but, as u can see, it's not fully rounded

[image]

Comment: If you use the digital color meter to look at the edges of a rounded view, you'll see that there are some pixels that are a blend of the background color and the view color, and that's what iOS does to make the edges look less jagged. I don't think there's anything you can do about it. It does the same thing whether you use rounded corners or a mask.

Comment: Can you create a second, slightly larger, rounded view that is empty with `backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]` and set the `borderColor` to be the same as your first view.  Then position the second view on top the first (in the zorder) with their centers being equal, thus the second view will cover the jaggy bits?

Comment: need to give half of layer width/height to cornerRadius e.g.: if view size is 100x100 then need to set corner radius to 50

Comment: Radius is half of height - which equals width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, the layer bounds is not big enough to cover the whole image after the clip of corner drawing. So, you can enlarge the layer's bounds a little bit to cover the view's image. Like this:

```
+ (void)setRoundedCornersByView:(UIView *)givenView roundAngle:(int)roundAngle borderWidth:(double)borderWidth borderColor:(UIColor *)borderColor alphaBorder:(double)alphaBorder
{
  CGFloat offset = 1.f; // .5f is also good enough
  givenView.layer.cornerRadius = roundAngle + offset;
  givenView.layer.borderColor = [[borderColor colorWithAlphaComponent:alphaBorder] CGColor];
  givenView.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth + offset;
  givenView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

  [givenView.layer setBounds:CGRectMake(-offset,
                                        -offset,
                                        CGRectGetWidth(givenView.frame)  + offset * 2.f,
                                        CGRectGetHeight(givenView.frame) + offset * 2.f)];
}
```